# prompt not working on date select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have 2 date fields, date started and date finished. I want to have a prompt for each, as in like on the page's first load, it will display the text "please select".

As you can see the code below, I have included prompt but it is not working.

```
<%= f.input :year_started, prompt: "Please select", as: :date, label: "Date started", start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year - 100, discard_day: true, order: [:month, :year], include_blank: true, default: nil, :input_html => { :class => 'profile-date' }, :required => false %>

<%= f.input :year_finished, prompt: "Please select", as: :date, label: "Date    finished", start_year: Date.today.year + 7, end_year: Date.today.year - 100, discard_day: true, order: [:month, :year], include_blank: true, default: nil, :input_html => { :class => 'profile-date' }, hint: "Or expected graduation month and year.", :required => false %>
```

Can someone please help me how to get this done in date select. Thanks

Comment: Try move `prompt:` option to the end of `f.input()` method, like that `<%= f.input some_log_arguments, :required => false,  prompt: "Please select" %>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply... its not working.

Comment: stop, i doesnt understand what you exactly want. cant you describe, you want `prompt` onclick or something else? where should be showed "Please select" ?

Comment: i want the date to have a default "please select" when the user does not touch it yet. Did you get it?

Comment: maybe you want `placeholder` instead of `prompt`, `prompt` raises popup with text and should works with some events like `onclick` or `onchange` e.t.c.

Comment: but place holders dont work in dropdown inputs. ie date select.

Comment: anyway it is unclear for me, what you have and what you want.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, prompt isn't a valid attribute for a date_field. A prompt can be used on a select box, and while date_fields may look like select boxes, they actually arent. Even placeholders won't work with date fields.

Comment: tnx for the reply. That makes sense. So is there any way to display a prompt or placeholder message-like  for date select? Do you think jquery is the only possible solution to display a placeholder like message for date select?